# delete appended characters of line of INI file in perl

Tags: perl

I am writing into an INI file, where the data gets appended and I want to delete remaining data.

Example:
In INI file Data was: `email_user=xyz@pqr.com` I want to write `email_user=abc@pqr.com`
When I write it, it appends and makes it: `email_user=abc@pqr.comcom`

I want to remove last characters(com which is rewritten).
I am doing following:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

seek(INI,-1,0);
print INI "email_user=abc@pqr.com";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`truncate`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/truncate.html) function to move the end of the file.

By the way, `seek(INI, -1, 0)` (one byte before the start of the file) makes no sense. It should be `seek(INI, 0, 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

If the records are not of the same length, this simple approach does not work. You cannot "insert" or "delete" bytes by overwriting a part of the file. You have to create a new file, write the new contents to it, and rename it to the old name at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
{
    local ($^I,@ARGV)=('~','file.ini');
    while (<>) {
        s/xyz/abc/;
        print;       
    }
}
```